# return html after ajax POST

Tags: ajax, django

I am using an ajax call to POST a form to create an object. Once the object is created in my views, I use the object instance to render a template, *footemplate* say.

What I would like to have happen is that *footemplate* is inserted into my current page, i.e. the one that contains the form. Particularly I am trying to add it to a div with id='result-container'. However when I return the rendered template it actually loads the page by itself.

views

```
def object_create(request):
    ....
    return render(request, template, template_context)
```

AJAX

```
$('#object-create').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var myform = document.getElementById('object-create');
    var fd = new FormData(myform );
    var post_url = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        data : fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            $('#result-container').html(data)
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("error")
        }
    });
});
```

How can I return the html as text only, instead of actually generating the page on its own?

EDIT:

It appears the problem is created by a popup construction that I am using. That is to say the form I am submitting is located in a popup that I populate using an AJAX GET request.

The HTML

```
<div class='popup-overlay' style='display:none;'></div>
<div class='popup-outer' style='display:none;'>
    <a id='popup-close'>X</a>
    <p>
        <div class='popup-inner'>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

The AJAX/jquery function that populates and displays the popup

```
function openpopup(data, url) {
    var data_ = data;
    var url_ = url;
    $.ajax({
        url: url_,
        type: 'GET',
        data: data_,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.popup-inner').html(data);
        }
    });
    $('.popup-overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.popup-outer').show();
};
```

When I load the form into the original page that the popup belongs to there is no problem and everything works as expected. I'm guessing something happens (or doesn't happen) in the line?

```
$('.popup-inner').html(data);
```

I don't understand what could possible go wrong here though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should remove the {% extends '' %} from your template?

Comment: I have managed to find what appears to be the culprit. The form that I am submitting via ajax is displayed inside of a popup, that I populate by an AJAX GET request. This seems to break the behaviour I am expecting, though I have no idea why. I have added the relevant code to the question.

Comment: can you double check if the form "action" attribute is set to the correct url?